# WebGLRenderer.render called with undefined camera

Tags: three.js

I'm using three.js and OrbitControls.js in combination, in a 3D app. Sometimes `WebGLRenderer.render` gets called with an undefined camera. This happens when I use the mouse to navigate the 3D model, using the controls delivered by OrbitConrols.
The undefined camera argument is weird, as my `animate` function (see code below) always calls `WebGLRenderer.render` with a well defined camera. Also, when instantiating OrbitControls, I give it a well defined camera. So the question is - how can it be that `WebGLRenderer.render` is at some point called with an undefined camera?

NOTE: The source code for the `WebGLRenderer.render` function can be seen in [line 20426](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/build/three.js) in the three.js source code.

I attempted to locate all the potential call sites by searching for the text string `render(`. There are 14 such matches on the string `render(`, but none of these gives an undefined camera as argument. Thus, the trail was cold.

I tried stack tracing from the callee (the function body of the `WebGLRenderer.render`function), but this merely lead back to some mix-it-all event hub. But it gave me a hint that the caller might be Javascript itself, calling from its DOM event system. That would explain why I couldn't find the call site in the three.js source code.

Thus perhaps the problem is associated with the point at which OrbitControls interacts with the Javascript event system. When initialising my app, I register an event on my OrbitControls instance. See code below. Could this be causing trouble? No camera is given as argument when this happens though :/

```
var myControls = require('../../instances/three/myControls');
var myRenderer = require('../../instances/three/myRenderer');

myControls.damping = 0.2;
myControls.domElement.addEventListener( 'change', myRenderer.render );
```

EDIT:
I'm using these versions:

```
three.js 0.81.0
three-orbit-controls 72.0.0
```

Comment: Your question is confusing - are you saying your `myCamera` variable is undefined? That's just a variable you make yourself. You control how it's instantiated and passed around. Without seeing how / where you make `myCamera` it's impossible to know what's going on.

Comment: Additionally the source code of almost every single example contains a simple scene and camera setup, and render loop http://threejs.org/examples/ . Hit the "view source" button on any example.

Comment: myCamera is defined, always. I have an if sentence that should yell at me if it ever becomes undefined (it can be seen in my quoted code above).
I have edited for clarity (hopefully) and added source code where I define myCamera.

Comment: somebody is calling render with an undefined camera, and it's not my animate function. The error happens when I click my mouse to drag the model around (using orbitcontrols). So perhaps orbitcontrols is playing around with an undefined camera. I need to track down the bad call site.

Comment: When you set up orbitcontrols do you pass it the camera as required? `new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );`

Comment: Please either show the code that is causing the problem and ask a specific question, or close this question. StackOverflow is the wrong medium for live debugging of code we can't see.

Comment: Could I pay you to have a live debug session with me using Skype and Teamviewer? Do note that this is a non trivial bug. My code has been working for years. I failed to notice when the mouse functions stopped working, but it likely happened when upgrading three.js or orbitcontrols.js. I can be reached at loldrup@gmail.com

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124144/discussion-between-loldrup-and-andy-ray).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, indeed the wrong-doing call to `render` was coming from some event system (the Javascript DOM event system). This module shows where the `render` function is given as callback to an event listener:

```
var myControls = require('../../instances/three/myControls');
var myRenderer = require('../../instances/three/myRenderer');

myControls.damping = 0.2;
myControls.addEventListener( 'change', myRenderer.render );

module.exports = {};
```

( where the `myControls` module looks like this:

```
var THREE = require('three');
var orbitControls = require('three-orbit-controls');
var myRenderer = require('../../instances/three/myRenderer');
var myCamera = require('./myCamera');
require('../../sideeffects/three/addCamera');

// add orbitControls to THREE:
var OrbitControls = orbitControls( THREE );

// make controls:
var controls = new OrbitControls( myCamera, myRenderer.domElement );

module.exports = controls;
```

)

However, it seems that OrbitControls.js has been changed in such a way that instances of the `OrbitControls` constructor are no longer DOM-elements. Thus, one CANNOT register events on them, as I was doing with the line:

```
myControls.addEventListener( 'change', myRenderer.render );
```

Instead, instances of the `OrbitControls` constructor has a new property: `domElement` which, as you might have guessed, is indeed a DOM element. Thus, I can fix the problem by changing the target of my event attachment to `myControls.domElement`. Thus the above line comes to look like this:

```
myControls.domElement.addEventListener( 'change', myRenderer.render );
```

and that solved the problem :)

EDIT:
It turns out that this line can actually be omitted completely! It is only necessary if there is no animation loop (a perpetual loop that calls `requestAnimationFrame` on each loop step)

Also, dampening can be enabled by doing this:

```
myControls.enableDamping = true;
```

and then adding `myControls.update();` somewhere in your animation loop.

Comment: What version of three.js are you using? Also study and understand the inline comments of http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_orbit.html before you respond.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I've eddited my question and answer appropriately. three.js 0.81.0
three-orbit-controls 72.0.0